# wp7 Haptic Feedback

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Where could I find documentation on how to implement haptic feedback for windows phone 7?  I want the phone to give short vibrations when a button is pressed.

Comment: I'd be really interested in user repsonse to this behaviour. Depending on the app and with what frequency button presses are required, as a user I'd be very wary if my phone vibrated every time I touched a button. That's not a behaviour I've seen anywhere before. Is it not possible to provide visual feedback on button press? Vibration varies slightly by device - will this matter? I'd also recommend giving the user a way to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Well, the default behavior for the "hardware" buttons on my samsung focus are that they buzz when I press them (back, windows key, and bing). Maybe that's just because they're capacitive buttons on the focus ... but I really like it for what it's worth :-)

Comment: I haven't got one to hand (left in office) but I thought they only caused a vibration if you tried to do something you couldn't (i.e. tried to navigate back when there was nowhere to navigate back to). The vibration indicates and exception, not a standard button press. The buttons you refer to are actually hardware buttons. From your question I thought you were trying to do this for all soft key presses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically all you need to make the phone vibrate is this:

```
VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
```

I suggest to read [this blog](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-12-Making-A-Phone-Vibrate.aspx) as it explains it quite well. The [other chapters](http://jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) are interesting too if you haven't already seen them.

Comment: I hadn't seen that blog yet.  Looks like a good resource!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I created a vibration class for my buttons so that its easy to call. Here is my code. Please give me +1 if you like.

```
public class Vibration
    {
        public static void VibrateOnButtonPress()
        {
            Microsoft.Devices.VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
            timer.Tick += (tsender, tevt) =>
            {
                var t = tsender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer;
                t.Stop();
                Microsoft.Devices.VibrateController.Default.Stop();
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use the XNA API to set the vibration of the "GamePad"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepad.setvibration.aspx

I'd be curious to know if you get it to work in silverlight, please comment after you try it :-)

Comment: ahh, few secs too late ... great answer Francesco :-)